# Analysis of Eye-tracking data(.CSV)

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plotly

I am trying to analyse and visualise my eye-tracking data that is in the CSV format. I have the gaze position of both eyes that I want to observe and how it's changing with time. So far, I have made a time vector and tried plotting the data but this is how its coming out :

[image]

But this is not how it's supposed to look, I have found a reference plot, which is what my data should be like:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-020-01400-9/figures/1

I am stuck on how I should approach this, I don't understand if it's the plotting parameters that are creating this issue or the pre-processing method itself. I pre-processed the data in R and downsampled it. The original eye data was recorded using SR research eye_tracking tool.

Edit: I could fix it! As mentioned by @Allan Cameron, I converted the y-axis variable to a numeric type, there were too many ticks on the y-axis which made my graph hard to read.

this is what I did :

```py
    df[['column1','column2']] = df[['column1','column2']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

This was my final plot :

[Final Corrected Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9FQM.png)

Comment: It looks like you need to convert the y axis variable to numeric. It's currently a character or factor variable. It's not really possible to help you more without reproducible data or code.

Comment: Alright, will it be okay if I make another post detailing the reproducible data?

Comment: You can [edit] this post